# Date Stays Null (Android)

Tags: java, android, date, nullpointerexception

I'm developing a simple calendar that stores events and the time of every event in 2 different hashmaps one for the events and the other for the time of the corresponding events here's my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat evTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    SimpleDateFormat month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM - YYYY");
    SimpleDateFormat day = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");


    HashMap<Date, ArrayList<String>> hmap = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Date, ArrayList<String>> hmap2 = new HashMap<>();

    void eventMaker(String d, String ev)  {

        Date date = null;
        Date time = null;
        try {
            date = day.parse(d);
            time = evTime.parse(d);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long epoch = date.getTime();
        Event event = new Event(Color.RED,epoch,ev);
        compactCalendar.addEvent(event);

        if(!hmap.containsKey(date)){
            ArrayList<String> eventList = new ArrayList<>();
            eventList.add(ev);
            hmap.put(date,eventList);

            ArrayList<String> eventTimes = new ArrayList<>();
            eventTimes.add(time.toString());
            hmap2.put(date,eventTimes);
        }
        else{
            ArrayList<String> eventList = hmap.get(date);
            eventList.add(ev);
            hmap.put(date,eventList);

            ArrayList<String> eventTimes = hmap2.get(date);
            eventTimes.add(time.toString());
            hmap2.put(date,eventTimes);
        }

        }
```

The problem is that the variable (time) stays null which lead to a crash, I want to know why?

Comment: What's the logcat say about the crash that you don't understand? Do you get a `ParseException`? If yes, then the date will be null

Comment: Are you sure not getting a stacktrace when parsing the dates in the try catch at the top?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys there's was a parse exception I didn't notice. I just misused parse and format methods...so sorry for this inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the nullpointerexception, but you need to address that ParseException differently.

Try throwing it

```
void eventMaker(String d, String ev)  throws ParseException
```

And remove the try catch there and do it wherever you call that method

---

Once you have that running, check the logcat message to see if your date format is wrong